# How to stop getting internet through the prepaid card and use only my home wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, 3g, mobile-data

I bought a 3G prepaid card that offers internet, but I want to stop getting Internet through the card and use WiFi to connect to his home router or certain WiFi networks of choice.

I know how to connect to WiFi. My question is how to shut off prepaid 3G internet, other than removing the card, which I find tedious.

The reason is simple, I want to use my card for phone calls only and I want to use the WiFi for Internet. Plus, my prepaid card internet is damn expensive.

Comment: What device & version of Android are you using? The instructions will vary based on the manufacturer's skin & OS release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android will always use WiFi once it is connected. You just have to disable mobile data. To do so go to `Settings` → `Mobile network settings` and uncheck `Data enabled`.

Answer (score 3):

*To manually start and stop internet:* Go to **`Settings -> Wireless and networks -> Mobile networks`** and disable **`Mobile data`**. This will stop internet connection through mobile network. Enable this to start internet again.

*To stop it permanently:*
Some application may start internet automatically, So to prevent accidental internet consumption, Create a new dummy **`Access Point Name`** in **`Mobile networks`** section and select that APN. So from next time your whenever you or any application try to connect to internet though mobile network it will try to connect though that dummy Access point and internet won't start. Internet will only work when you connect to WiFi.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible (or should be) that apps enable mobile data without the prior confirmation by the user. The second paragraph is not really necessary, but it won't hurt and it in may be needed if you gave an app root.

Comment: Ahh, are you suggesting that apps to which I confirmed mobile data will ignore the Mobile Data uncheck and continue to suck Internet through my 3G??

Comment: As Flow noted, they should not. Also, removing the APN or creating a dummy does not work for all carriers. In Germany, e.g. O2 and now also E-Plus do not require any APN configuration for mobile data (E-Plus says they want to make it "easier" for the user this way).

Comment: My mistake. This used to happen in my nokia's symbian, that apps starting internet by themselves. Android mobile data control is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and tap SIM management and select always ask for mobile data connection... That is all...

Comment: Where do you have an "always ask" option there? What Android version is that? I've never seen this option on any of my devices (admittedly, not running anything with 4.2 or up – so a newer version *might* have this). So if you mean to "disable mobile data", that [was already suggested in another answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/47495/16575).